# Как сделать форму маленькой , когда уже применил к ней свойство WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

Tags: c#, winforms

увеличил форму, но я не могу её сделать обратно маленькой, мне кажется что нужно менять размеры ( вручную ), но так как я с этим ещё никогда не работал, то не знаю как это делается

Comment: Пробовали `FormWindowState.Normal`?

Comment: только что написал этот вопрос и увидел FormWindowState.Normal; Господи.... так протупить, это же проще простого, спасибо большое !

Comment: Ничего страшного, такое со всеми бывает. Зато теперь у нас есть ответ и на такой вопрос :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте команду

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```